# How to find the difference between two lists of dictionaries?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, set

I have two lists of dictionaries and I'd like to find the difference between them (i.e. what exists in the first list but not the second, and what exists in the second list but not the first list).

The issue is that it is a list of dictionaries

```
a = [{'a': '1'}, {'c': '2'}]
b = [{'a': '1'}, {'b': '2'}]

set(a) - set(b)
```

Result

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

Desired Result:

```
{'c': '2'}
```

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: are your dictionaries really only single items?  if so, wouldn't make more sense to make the list into a single dictionary?

Comment: nope, they are multiple items (around 15 each most likely) and this would be a list of about 3000 to 1000 dictoinaries in each list

Comment: Could you check your desired result. According to your definition you are looking of a [symmetric difference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use the `in` operator to see if it is in the list

```
a = [{'a': '1'}, {'c': '2'}]
b = [{'a': '1'}, {'b': '2'}]

>>> {'a':'1'} in a
True
>>> {'a':'1'} in b
True

>>> [i for i in a if i not in b]
[{'c': '2'}]
```

Answer (score 4):

> I'd like to find the difference between them (i.e. *what exists in the first list but not the second, and what exists in the second list but not the first list*)

According to your definition, you looking for a [Symmetric difference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference):

```
>>> import itertools

>>> a = [{'a': '1'}, {'c': '2'}]
>>> b = [{'a': '1'}, {'b': '2'}]
>>> intersec = [item for item in a if item in b]
>>> sym_diff = [item for item in itertools.chain(a,b) if item not in intersec]

>>> intersec
[{'a': '1'}]
>>> sym_diff
[{'c': '2'}, {'b': '2'}
```

Alternatively (using the [*plain* difference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Difference_%28set_theory%29#Relative_complement) as given in your example):

```
>>> a_minus_b = [item for item in a if item not in b]
>>> b_minus_a = [item for item in b if item not in a]
>>> sym_diff = list(itertools.chain(a_minus_b,b_minus_a))

>>> a_minus_b
[{'c': '2'}]
>>> b_minus_a
[{'b': '2'}]
>>> sym_diff
[{'c': '2'}, {'b': '2'}]
```

Comment: This was referenced in one of the answers but I believe this is exactly what the OP wanted here...so +1. One Question, couldn't you just use `+` operator to concatenate `a_minis_b` and `b_minus_a` into `sym_diff` instead of using `itertools.chain`?

Comment: @KhalilAmmour-خليلعمور Yes you can. But using `itertools.chain()` you don't have to build the resulting list in memory before using it. Especially important for "big" lists. In order to be a little bit more consistent with that though, I should have use a generator instead of a list comprehension here: `a_minus_b = (item for item in a if item not in b)`. But this would be more tricky in that sample code, as a generator consumes items when you use them.

Comment: Ahah...I see...so that was for memory optimitzation, can you show me an example with generator, may be through editing your answer, if you will?

Answer (score 1):

You can also you [filter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) with a `lambda`:

If you want the different items in each list:

```
print filter(lambda x: x not in b,a) + filter(lambda x: x not in a,b)

[{'c': '2'}, {'b': '2'}]
```

Or just `filter(lambda x: x not in b,a)` to get the elements in `a` but not in `b`
If you don't want to create the full list of dicts in memory you can use `itertools.ifilter`

```
from itertools import ifilter

diff = ifilter(lambda x: x not in b,a)
```

Then just iterate over diff:

```
for uniq in diff:
   print uniq
```