# How to find the difference between two lists of dictionaries checking the key-value pair

Tags: python, list, csv, dictionary

I've already searched for a solution to my problem but with no success. Part of the solution for my problem is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25552972/how-to-find-the-difference-between-two-lists-of-dictionaries), but this does not solve it all.

I have two lists of dictionaries like this - each dictionary is written to a csv file but I read the contents to the following variables:

```
list1 = [{a:1, b:2, c:3}, {a:4, b:5, c:6}, {a:7, b:8, c:9}]
list2 = [{b:2, a:1, c:3}, {c:6, b:5, a:4}, {b:8, a:7, c:9}]
```

Using the solution of the link above, ie:

```
>>> import itertools

>>> a = [{'a': '1'}, {'c': '2'}]
>>> b = [{'a': '1'}, {'b': '2'}]
>>> intersec = [item for item in a if item in b]
>>> sym_diff = [item for item in itertools.chain(a,b) if item not in intersec]
```

I get no matches because the order of the dictionary is different. But in fact, both lists are the same. How can I check this? Do I have to sort the dictionaries before writing them to the csv file? Can this be a solution?

This is my major problem at the moment but I have another issue also. It would be great to be able to make this match check but ignoring one or more keys defined by me. Is this also possible?

**EDIT: I have the dicitonaries in a csv file and I'm reading them with the following code:**

```
def read_csv_file(self, filename):
    '''Read CSV file and return its content as a Python list.'''
    f = open(filename, 'r')
    csvfile = csv.reader(f)
    f.close
    return [row for row in csvfile]
```

This is very important because I think the problem is that after reading the values from the csv it's not dictionaries anymore, so the order has to be the same.

**EDIT2: sample of the csv file (3 lines, it's creating an empty line but that's not an issue...)**

```
"{u'Deletion': '0', u'Source': 'Not Applicable', u'Status': ''}"

"{u'Deletion': '0', u'Source': 'Not Applicable', u'Status': ''}"
```

Comment: Can you post an example of your csv file, to see how it is formatted?

Comment: if you are reading each row from this CSV file then what `list2` is for?

Comment: I'm reading from two different csv's and then comparing them.

Comment: So if I've understood well, you are reading from two csv files and storing the dictionaries in lists, then you want to get the difference & intersection between the two lists, right?

Comment: Reading from your csv file using `csv.reader()` will return to you a list of strings, not a dictionary..!

Comment: Sorry about that!!! I'm creating the csv's in two different machines at different times. After creating the second one, I read both and I compare them. The rest is the story you already know...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80878/discussion-between-zephirus-and-khalil-ammour--).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part of this solution was found by OP as per our last CHAT conversation, it was to convert a string into dictionary using [ast](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html) module.

Now using this module to convert every row read by the `csv.reader()` as it returns a list of strings, which would be a list of one string in case of OP's CVS file, then append this dictionary into a list. After that using list comprehension with `itertools.chain`, we can get the difference between the two lists.

```
import csv
import ast
import itertools

def csvToList(myCSVFile):

    '''This function is used to convert strings returned by csv.reader() into List of dictionaries'''

        f = open(myCSVFile, 'r')
        l = []
        try:
            reader = csv.reader(f)
            for row in reader:
                if row: #as you mentioned in your 2nd edit that you could have empty rows.
                    l.append(ast.literal_eval(row[0]))
        finally:
            f.close()        
        return l

list1 = csvToList('myCSV1.csv')
list2 = csvToList('myCSV2.csv')

l1_sub_l2  = [d for d in list1 if d not in list2]
l2_sub_l1  = [d for d in list2 if d not in list1]
list_difference = list(itertools.chain(l1_sub_l2, l2_sub_l1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to double check your code. I'm not getting the issue you're bringing up.

```
list1 = [{a:1, b:2, c:3}, {a:4, b:5, c:6}, {a:7, b:8, c:9}]
list2 = [{b:2, a:1, c:3}, {c:6, b:5, a:4}, {b:8, a:7, c:9}]

list1 = [{'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}, {'a':4, 'b':5, 'c':7}, {'a':7, 'b':8, 'c':9}]
list2 = [{'b':2, 'a':1, 'c':3}, {'c':6, 'b':2, 'a':4}, {'b':8, 'a':7, 'c':9}]
intersec = [item for item in list1 if item in list2]
sym_diff = [item for item in itertools.chain(list1,list2) if item not in intersec]

print(intersec)
print(sym_diff)

>>>[{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}, {'a': 4, 'c': 6, 'b': 5}, {'a': 7, 'c': 9, 'b': 8}]
>>>>[]
```

If I change list1 and list 2 (middle dictionary):

```
list1 = [{'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}, {'a':7, 'b':5, 'c':2}, {'a':7, 'b':8, 'c':9}]
list2 = [{'b':2, 'a':1, 'c':3}, {'c':6, 'b':5, 'a':4}, {'b':8, 'a':7, 'c':9}]
```

Running same code:

```
[{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}, {'a': 7, 'c': 9, 'b': 8}]
[{'a': 7, 'c': 2, 'b': 5}, {'a': 4, 'c': 6, 'b': 5}]
```

The provided code in the link seems to be working fine. The order of the dictionary or a list does not matter in python.

Comment: Hi Leb. I edited my question with an important information. I think that after reading the csv file I'm dealng with strings, not dictionaries. So my question at this moment is if I can treat this as dictionaries (and how to do it if reading from csv) or, if the sort before saving to csv is a proper solution.

Answer (score -1):

Use a [dictionary comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) instead of a list comprehension in your return.

Comment: I think I got this working in Python. Unfortunately I also need it to work with jython and it's giving me this error: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Invalid method Code length 240222 in class file org/python/pycode/_pyx2


java.lang.ClassFormatError: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Invalid method Code length 240222 in class file org/python/pycode/_pyx2

Comment: I've managed to solve the Jython issue but I'm still struggling with the compare. I tried to sort the dictionaries alphabetically before adding them to the csv but without success.