# Find difference of list of dictionary Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, set

I have 2 Lists in Python;

```
listA = [{'b': '3'}, {'b': '4'}]
listB = [{'a': '3'}, {'b': '3'}]
```

I tried to convert it to set it showed unhashable type: 'dict'

The operation i was trying to do is

```
list[(set(listA)).difference(set(listB))]
```

So what can be done with my list to achieve same functionality? Thanks

Comment: Why are there two b keys in the first list? What's the expected output?

Comment: To be used in sets or as keys for a dictionary the type must be immutable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find the difference between two lists of dictionaries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25552972/how-to-find-the-difference-between-two-lists-of-dictionaries)

Comment: listA: critical issues for a list of scenarios
listB: No issues for a list of scenarios
b,a: Users
3,4: equipment Id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `dict.items()` to get tuples, which could be converted to `set` type

```
setA = set(chain(*[e.items() for e in listA]))
setB = set(chain(*[e.items() for e in listB]))

print setA.symmetric_difference(setB)
```

The output is

```
set([('a', '3'), ('b', '4')])
```

Comment: print setA.difference(setB)

Comment: symmetric_difference return all elements that are in exactly one of the sets.

Answer (score 7):

Do it with simple list comprehension.

```
>>> [i for i in listA if i not in listB]
[{'b': '4'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of ifilterfalse from itertools.

```
list(itertools.ifilterfalse(lambda x: x in listA, listB)) + list(itertools.ifilterfalse(lambda x: x in listB, listA))
```

The output will be

```
[{'b': '4'}, {'a': '3'}]
```